# Multiprocessing using new processes

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I need to parallelize a large computation. This should work in such a way that i have a fixed number of processes running in parallel at any time, but each individual process is only used for one input and than closed. The next input is processed using a new process. E.g 30 inputs result in 30 processes but only 3 of them run in parallel at any given time.
I had a look at the multiprocessing module, but could not figure out a way to use a fresh process for every input.

Advice would be appreciated

Comment: read about `multiprocessing.pool` or `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor`, also provide your code so anyone can answer you.

Comment: User ProcessPoolExecutor and its map() function. When you construct the executor specify the *max_workers* parameter to manage the maximum number of concurrent processes

Comment: @AhmedAEK thanks for the advice, i did not know what to search for. I'll check this out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have a pool process exist only for a single task that has been submitted to the pool and then terminate so that a new process must be created to keep the pool size constant, then I don't believe it can be done with `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor`. However, the `multiprocessing.pool.Pool` initializer has a *maxtasksperchild* argument that you could set to 1 to achieve this. For example:

```py
from os import getpid

def square(x):
    print(getpid(), flush=True)
    return x * x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from multiprocessing.pool import Pool

    # Create a pool size of 4:
    with Pool(processes=4, maxtasksperchild=1) as pool:
        print(pool.map(square, (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)))
```

Prints:

```
5320
14256
5040
15552
16768
852
4564
3720
[1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64]
```

Comment: Thanks! I must have overlooked the maxtasksperchild argument.